# How to prove that $X+Y \mod p$ is indpendent from $X$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

We have a group $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and some random variable $X$ and $Y$ with this domain. We have that $Y$ is chosen uniformly at random, thus each element from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with probability $\frac{1}{p}$. Further, we have that $X$ and $Y$ are Independent. 
How do we prove that $X+Y \mod p$ is uniformly at random and independent from $X$ then?

My idea was:

$$Pr[X+Y \mod p = z \mid X=x]= Pr[Y= z - x \mod p ]=\frac{1}{p}$$ for any $x, z \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. Is this correct? Is this a proof that $X+Y \mod p$ and $X$ are independent?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: *Assuming that X and Y are independent*, yes this is a proof (but please modify the title, at present it does not correspond to the body of the question).

Comment: Yes, sorry. $X$ and $Y$ are Independent. Is it better now?

Comment: Independent from... X, if Y is uniform, not from Y.